Avoid running tests individually if they've already run inside a suite
I'm using JUnit 5. I have tests that are declared in a @Suite. When I run the tests for the whole project, JUnit 5 runs the suite but also re-runs the tests individually. Is there a generic way to stop this behavior. I don't want to configure my build script (e.g. Maven or Gradle) to run the suite explicitly, nor do I want to configure the run command with the specific suite. I'm looking for something such as "runTestsOnce" or similar.
Minimal reproducible example:
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class ExampleClass {

  @Test
  public void test() {
    System.out.println("test");
  }

}
//--------------------
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasses;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

@Suite
@SelectClasses({
  ExampleClass.class
})
public class ExampleSuite {
}

By running gradle test, I get the following output which shows that the ExampleClass#test() method is executed twice, once for the @Suite and once individually:
> Task :test

ExampleSuite > JUnit Jupiter > ExampleClass > test() STANDARD_OUT
    test

ExampleClass > test() STANDARD_OUT
    test

This is not a Gradle issue, any build system that runs JUnit tests results in the same behavior.

What you describe does not sound normal.  Please present a [mre] demonstrating the behavior.  Be sure to include details of how you are launching the tests.

Do not vote to close the question before I can provide the (unneeded) minimal reproducible example, thanks

Without the mre this question is unanswerable. You calling it unneeded makes me more likely to flag for closure. Just saying.

Not sure this will work but.. you could annotate the Suite class with Ignore.  It should be skipped in general execution but still allow you to directly invoke the class

@vsfDawg hmmm that's a weird but interesting hack

@JohnBollinger added MRE

I'd say this behaviour is to be expected if:

Both junit-jupiter and junit-platform are in the list of included test engines
ExampleClass is accepted by your inlude patterns for Junit.


@johanneslink interesting observation but junit-platform is supposed to be part of the JUnit5 junit-jupiter ecosystem, it's not a JUnit4 thing. From my understanding it's an extension of junit-jupiter and thus should properly cooperate, it's not a different engine.

I wonder if the easiest option would be to just have another "pseudo suite" that selects all not-truly-part-of-a-suite tests? Then configure JUnit to only include the junit-platform-suite engine (e.g,, in Gradle, includeEngines("junit-platform-suite")). Of course, the junit-platform engine still needs to be on the test class-path, since the junit-platform-suite engine needs another engine to actually execute the tests.

Note each engine is executed separately by default (because by default, all engines on the class-path are used directly). If a test is selected by multiple engines then that test will be executed multiple times. But you need at least one other engine, because the junit-platform-suite engine relies on other "real" engines for test execution. So, you either need to configure your environment so the tests selected by each engine don't intersect (not exactly sure how, perhaps via JUnit configurations or even separate build tasks), or only execute suites (as described in my previous comment).

It seems that the root cause is clear. The suite and the baseline are two distinct engines. By default all engines are executed and they all execute the respective tests they have detected. I don't see a "direct" solution, I'd expect the suite to be an extension of the baseline engine, not an engine itself.

@pentakon The suite engine can execute tests from any other engine. That's why it cannot just be an extension of JUnit Jupiter. If you accept that and include/exclude engines respectively, I just don't see a problem.
